# Combining two functions: walk through directory, write each file to DB

Tags: python, postgresql, for-loop

If I have one function called list_files(that takes a directory as an argument and "os.walks" through the folder structure) and another function called main(that takes a file as an argument and saves it to a DB), how would I nest them such that every file in the directory structure gets written to the DB?  I tried the for loop below, but it's not working.

I know that the os.walk returns a list that needs to be converted to a string.  And I know I'm doing it wrong.

```
"""A tool for saving files to and from a postgresql db.
"""
import os
import sys
import argparse
import psycopg2

db_conn_str = "postgresql://word:word@111.11.111.1:5432/DBNAME"
create_table_stm = """
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS files (
    id serial primary key,
    orig_filename text not null,
    file_data bytea not null
)
"""

# Walk through the directory
def list_files(dir):
    r = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for name in files:
            r.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return r


def main(argv):
    for each_file in list_files(''.join(r)):
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser_action = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
        parser_action.add_argument("--store", action='store_const', const=True, help="Load an image from the named file and save it in the DB")
        parser_action.add_argument("--fetch", type=int, help="Fetch an image from the DB and store it in the named file, overwriting it if it exists. Takes the database file identifier as an argument.", metavar='42')
        parser.add_argument("filename", help="Name of file to write to / fetch from")
        args = parser.parse_args(argv[1:])

        conn = psycopg2.connect(db_conn_str)
        curs = conn.cursor()


        if args.store:
                # This should just be f.read() (dropping the psycopg2.Binary) when using Python 3 -- the current version is written for Python 2.7
            with open(args.filename,'rb') as f:
                filedata = psycopg2.Binary(f.read())
                curs.execute("INSERT INTO files(id, orig_filename, file_data) VALUES (DEFAULT,%s,%s) RETURNING id", (args.filename, filedata))
                print curs
                returned_id = curs.fetchone()[0]
            print("Stored {0} into DB record {1}".format(args.filename, returned_id))
            conn.commit()

        elif args.fetch is not None:
            with open(args.filename,'wb') as f:
                curs.execute("SELECT file_data, orig_filename FROM files WHERE id = %s", (int(args.fetch),))
                (file_data, orig_filename) = curs.fetchone()
                f.write(file_data)
            print("Fetched {0} into file {1}; original filename was {2}".format(args.fetch, args.filename, orig_filename))

        conn.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: r is local to another function declaration. so technically it wont give expected results.

Comment: When you say "it's not working", what does that mean?  Only some records get inserted, nothing does, etc.?  Is the list_files returning the proper results?

Comment: Nothing gets written into the DB.  And I know the main() function works because I've written individual files to the DB with it.  Something is broken now that I've attempted to introduce os.walk() through a directory (instead of writing single files).

Comment: When you print the results from `list_files` does it return what you were hoping for?  If it is returning what you want, is your loop executing the way you expect? i.e. if you add a bunch of print statements to debug does it hit all of those print statements the way you expect

Comment: `r` looks like it's not defined in global or local scope. Is that not throwing a `NameError`? It also doesn't look like you are writing `each_file` anywhere. I see `args.filename` being opened, but I don't see the files being explicitly written to the table. Maybe I'm missing something here

Comment: It seems I need to get rid of the list_files and instead walk through within the main() function.  Is that correct?
`for root, dirs, files in os.walk(u".", topdown=False):
   for name in files:
      print(os.path.join(root, name))
   for name in dirs:
      print(os.path.join(root, name))`